# How to name model instances based on a value chosen in ModelChoiceField in Django?

Tags: python, django

I have problem with Django. I have class Typy and I want to name instances of this class based on username and field *match_to_bet* which is ModelChoiceField and is generated from base.

```
class Typy(models.Model):
    users = (('user_1', 'user_1'),
        ('user_2', 'user_2'))
    user = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, choices=users)

    mecz = models.ForeignKey('Mecz', on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=0)
    choice = Mecz.objects.values()
    match_to_bet = ModelChoiceField(queryset=choice, empty_label=None)

    bet_home = models.BigIntegerField()
    bet_away = models.BigIntegerField()

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.user) + '_' + str(self.match_to_bet.__str__())
```

So far I get name with object's adress and have no idea how to change code to get names 'user'_'option chosen in *match_to_bet*'
[current instances names](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rlt3l.png)

Comment: `ModelChoiceField` should be used on `Form`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ModelChoiceField is used in Forms not in Models.

You want CharField or IntegerField with choice attribute.

Then you can do get_fieldname_display()